# How to drive a E1144CS021 (EPD display)?

Tags: display, e-ink

I was searching for EPD displays and came across [this Pervasive Displays EPD](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/E1144CS021/E1144CS021-ND/5046789), but after searching in the manufacturer's website, I couldn't find any information on how to actually use it. There are some [pre-made kits](http://www.pervasivedisplays.com/kits/ext2_kit), but those are intended for evaluation use, and though the schematics are available, there are no design descriptions.

How would one drive such a display? It uses an SPI interface, but what signals should be sent to it? What about all the other pins, how should they be configured?

Comment: Check this link:
http://repaper.org/
it contains all their code samples and relevant commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you don't.  Or rather you only do it by connecting to a timing controller.

EPD's are not a simple drive a voltage and then you see an image.  they require complex waveforms and timing to move the particles around in the display. Indirect evidence of this is in section three of a data-sheet for that part: Here is as snipped picture.

[image]

This is not a development for even experienced EE's who don't have a display or EPD background.

However, there are a number of micro-controllers that have specific timing controllers built into them to drive EPD's. Grab one of those.